# Jaydebeapi.connect() from Databricks

Tags: database-connection, databricks, teradata, jaydebeapi, data-connections

I am able to read and write the data from databricks to Teradata but not able to run jaydebeapi.connect() funtion.

```
import jaydebeapi
jdbc_driver_loc ='dbfs:/FileStore/jars/bad3070d_dcf9_445a_ad2f_a83066001166-terajdbc_20_00_00_06-6121b.jar,dbfs:/FileStore/jars/008ecc1e_67f3_44f6_b2a4_51753cd1fd07-tdgssconfig.jar' 
config_dict={"JDBCURL":"jdbc:?,LOGMECH=LDAP","JDBCDriver":"com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver","DB_User":"?","DB_PWD":"?"} 
jdbcUrl=config_dict["JDBCURL"]
jdbcDriver =config_dict["JDBCDriver"]
user=config_dict["DB_User"]
password=config_dict["DB_PWD"]
print(jdbcDriver)
print(jdbcUrl)
jars=["dbfs:/FileStore/jars/bad3070d_dcf9_445a_ad2f_a83066001166-terajdbc_20_00_00_06-6121b.jar","dbfs:/FileStore/jars/008ecc1e_67f3_44f6_b2a4_51753cd1fd07-tdgssconfig.jar"]
conn = jaydebeapi.connect('com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver',jdbcUrl,[user,password],jars)
```

> error : TypeError: Class com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver is not found

I am able to connect manually with same teradata connection.

I tried to change the driver as well the path.

Comment: Maybe try /dbfs/FileStore/jars... instead of dbfs:/FileStore/jars... ?